# Image dialog hides incorrectly while editing a post inline

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, uploader

There is a bug with escape when canceling the image uploader when editing a post inline (i.e. with the 2k edit posts privilege)

Browser: Chrome 50.0.xxx, did not test other browsers

**Steps:**

1. Edit any question.
2. Click on the image icon in the toolbar.
3. Hit escape key on your keyboard.

**Expected:**

The image dialog will close with the question still editable

**Actual:**

The image dialog remains open and the question is no longer editable. If you hit the escape key a second time, the image dialog hides.

Comment: The actual bug is that the first ESC click is handled by the editor itself, closing it - only the second one is handled by the uploader. Should be reversed. Also, not relevant for suggested edits or editing own posts with less than 2k reputation, only for inline editing that can be canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - that's... suboptimal.

I've updated the scripts so the image uploader takes focus once it is loaded - this ensures that events are captured in the right order, meaning that it will close on hitting esc instead of the inline editor.

With you in the next build.